# Azure DevOps Services permission for work item templates

Tags: tfs-workitem, workitem, azure-devops-services

We are using multiple project teams in a project with seperated boards and templates. Until last week this construct works fine for us. Now a bunch of users would like to create workitems based on a template in another projectteams board. (users aren't members of the team). They can't see the templates, but the creation of a base workitem works as expected. Is there a seperated permission for read/edit templates of a projectteam?

I nearly checked every team based permission section including the area based permissions. Even the microsoft documentation didn't deliver the wished infomation...

So maybe someone out here can help us ;)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In order for your team members to have access to apply the templates you've created for them, they'll need to be both:

1. A contributor within the project that you've created the templates within.
2. A member of the team in which you created the work items.

This is nestled within Microsoft's Work Item Template Documentation under "Prerequisites". You can find it here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#timeouts